# Continuity of the function $g(e^{it})=f(t)$ defined on $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ continuous and $2\pi $ periodic. In Harro Heuser: Analysis 2 (page 65) it is left to the reader to show that the function $g(e^{it})=f(t)$ defined by : $$g: S\rightarrow \mathbb{C}; S=\{z\in \mathbb{C} ||z|=1 \}  $$

is continuous

What I have tried:

continuous maps under continuous functions are again continuous so it is enough if one shows that $y(t) = e^{it}$ is continuous on $t\in[0,2\pi]$

$\lim_{t\rightarrow a } e^{it} = e^{ia}$ is true because : $$|e^{it}-e^{ia}|= |e^{ia}|\cdot|e^{(t-a)}-1| = |t-a+\frac{(t-a)^2}{2!}+...| $$$$ = |t-a|\cdot|1+\frac{t-a}{2!}+\frac{(t-a)^2}{3!}...| \le |t-a|\cdot |e^{t-a}|$$

so in a compact neighbourhood we can bound $e^{it}$  and $|t-a|$

and $|e^{it}-e^{ia}|$ can be chosen arbitrarily small

Is this correct? How can one show the continuity of this function more directly?

Comment: suppose $g$ not continuous, but $g(e^{it})$ continuous and $e^{it}$ continuous, try to derive a contradiction? And I agree that you need compactness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb C$ be an open set.
Then $g^{-1}(U)$ is the image of the set $V=f^{-1}(U)$ under $t\mapsto e^{it}$.
Since $f$ is continuous, we know that $V$ is open.
We don't need continuity of the exponential, but rather that it is *open*, that is:

> If $V\subseteq \mathbb R$ is open then $e^{iV}\subseteq S$ is open.

Therefoer we have that $g^{-1}(U)$ is open in $S$, hence $g$ continuous.

To prove the claim that $\mathbb R\to S,t\mapsto e^{it}$ is open, show that
$$ |a-(b+2k\pi)|\le \pi\cdot |e^{ia}-e^{ib}|\quad\text{for suitable }k\in\mathbb Z.$$

Comment: How do you get to the last line e.g. to show that it is open prove that  $|a-(b+2k\pi)|\le \pi \cdot | e^{ia}-e^{ib} |$ for suitable $k\in \mathbb{Z}$